# Compare Dicom image in MATLAB (in one file)

Tags: matlab, dicom

for my project i have to segment the abnormalities in a CT brain image.
I want to do that by comparing the right side of the brain with the left side. This could be done
by using the intensity difference of the image. For example, blood is brighter than the brain tissue in 
CT images. Due to the fact that the right and left side of the brain are nearly symmetric, it is possible
to find a abnormality in one side by comparing that with the other side. Using Matlab, I want to work
with the Dicom files of the CT images. I want to segment the abnormal area by comparing both sides of the brain.
After segmenting the abnormalities in 2D, I want to register the 2D images and create a 3D reconstruction.
Does anyone perhaps know, what the best coding method is (in Matlab) for comparing the left and right side of a Dicom image?

Comment: If you think my answer was the one you were looking for, please consider it marking as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865503000497
It explains how to find the symmetry plane in 3D MRI images, but the method should also work on CT. First you search for the center of mass in your image. Next you calculate the axes of the ellipsoid of inertia and evaluate the symmetry. Finally, you can improve the symmetry plane using the downhill simplex method.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: here is how I would tackle this problem:

1. search for the center of mass `R`

   ```
   ind = find(ones(size(image)));
   ind = reshape(ind, size(image,1), size(image,2), size(image,3)); %for a 3D volume
   [x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(image), ind); %for a 3D volume
   Rx = image.*x;
   Ry = image.*y;
   Rz = image.*z;
   Rx = round(1/sum(image(:)) * sum(Rx(:)));
   Ry = round(1/sum(image(:)) * sum(Ry(:)));
   Rz = round(1/sum(image(:)) * sum(Rz(:)));
   ```

   `Rx, Ry`and `Rz`now contain the position of the center of mass in your image. The code is easily adaptable to 2D.
2. Now, look for the axes of the ellipsoid of inertia:

   ```
   for p=0:2
       for q=0:2
           for r=0:2
               if p+q+r==2
                   integr = image.*(x-Rx).^p.*(y-Ry).^q.*(z-Rz).^r;
                   m = sum(integr(:));
                   if p==2, xx=1; yy=1;  
                   elseif p>0 && q>0, xx=1; yy=2;
                   elseif p>0 && r>0, xx=1; yy=3;
                   elseif q==2, xx=2; yy=2;
                   elseif q>0 && r>0, xx=2; yy=3;                    
                   elseif r==2, xx=3; yy=3; 
                   end
                   M(xx,yy) = m;
                   M(yy,xx) = m;
               end
           end
       end
   end

   [V,~] = eig(M);
   ```

   The matrix `V` contains the directions of the axes of the ellipsoid of inertia. These are first guesses for the symmetry plane.
3. Evaluate the symmetry. This is the hard part, because you have to rotate the image around all three (or two, in 2D) possible symmetry planes. I have used the `affine3D` and `imwarp` commands, but it's quite cumbersome. Make sure to define the different axes through the center of mass found before. A possible measure of symmetry is `mu = 1 - ||image - mirrored_ image||^2 / (2*||image||^2)`. The axis with the highest `mu` value is the best symmetry plane.
4. If you are not happy about the symmetry axis, you can improve it using the downhill simplex method, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method
5. Now you have you original image and the mirrored image around the midsagittal plane. Subtracting both should give you an idea of abnormalities.

I hope this is clear. For more information, please check the excellent paper by Tuzikov et al. mentioned above.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my text in a minute :) I have implemented the method myself, but it's about 1000 lines of code, so not really feasible to put it all here. Moreover, I don't think I've implemented the algorithm in the most efficient way :)